# Angular2 date and time picker

Tags: angular, datetime

I can't seem to be able to create a proper date and time picker for my angular2 app. Can someone help me set it up?

I've tried the following techniques:
Ng2-datetime:
I imported it into the main app.module:

```
import { NKDatetimeModule } from 'ng2-datetime/ng2-datetime';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  NKDatetimeModule,
..
 ],
```

and in the template:

```
<datetime [(ngModel)]="startDate"></datetime>
```

This yields in the template not being recognizable: 'datetime' is not a known element

My apps is composed from a few modules, each has its own app module. So when I tried taking the above definitions to the module definitions of the sub module, I get '$(...).datepicker is not a function'
Technical details: 
I use angular-cli 2.4.8
with the following packages:

```
 "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.6.4",
 "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "2.1.25",
 "bootstrap-timepicker": "^0.5.2",
 "jquery": "3.1.1",
 "moment": "2.17.1",
 "ng2-bootstrap": "1.3.3",
 "ng2-datetime": "^1.3.2",
 "ng2-datetime-picker": "^0.14.7",
```

I also tried separating it into date input and time input, using pipe to display the desired format. This doesn't show the content of the date or time.

```
<input [type]="'date'" [model]="startDate" | date: 'MM/DD/YYYY'"</input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pull out the package under the `node_modules` folder to a subfolder within your src directory so that it will treated like a local dependency.

See the example from the author:

https://github.com/nkalinov/ng2-datetime/tree/master/src

External dependencies are usually under `node_modules` and packaged for distribution. For example, the distribution could include a UMD, CJS, and AMD bundles, and deployed as JS files only.  This is not how the ng2-datetime package was deployed. Until the author updates the package to be more module friendly, you'll have to just copy the implementation to the src folder whenever there is an update.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It still gives me the error $(..).datepicker is not a function

Comment: DId you follow these instructions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datetime-picker. Did you install @types/jquery: npm install @types/jquery?

Comment: Thanks again. I did. Those instructions do not include instructions for angular-cli. They include instructions for system,js